# Typescript: Type T is not assignable to type 'never' when using Exclude

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, typeerror

I am trying have a:

- list of all field names
- list of unsortable field names

I am trying to infer whether `ugh` is the complement of unsortable.

```
function isUnsortableField<All extends string | number | symbol, T extends All, K extends Exclude<All, T>>(unsortable: Array<K>, field: All): field is T {
  return !!unsortable.find((f) => f === field)
}

const allFields = ['bar', 'zee'] as const;
const unsortableOnes: Array<typeof allFields[number]> = ['bar'];

const ugh = isUnsortableField(unsortableOnes, 'bar');
```

However I get:

```
Argument of type '("bar" | "zee")[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

EDIT: 1000 rubber ducks later, fix:
was: `unsortable: Array<K>` but should've been `unsortable: Array<T>`

```
function isSortableField<
  All extends PropertyKey,
  Unsorted extends All,
  K extends Exclude<All, Unsorted>
>(unsortable: Array<Unsorted>, field: All): field is K {
  return !unsortable.find((f) => f === field);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `unsortable`?

Comment: It' just a use-case. I have a set A and a subset of A called B (fields vs unsortable fields). I want to assert the if an element is in A and !B

Comment: Not 100% sure what problem your trying to solve.  If you just want to make sure something is inside an array in a typescript safe / runtime way, doing `unsortableOnes.includes('bar')` works.  IOW: if you did `unsortableOnes.includes('xyz')` typescript would complain.

Comment: In the 3rd generic parameter of your function you are Excluding from All something that extends All, which will always resolve to `never`

Answer (score 0):

In the 3rd generic parameter of your function you are Extending from All something that extends All, and since the T is a superset of All, it will exclude everything and resolve to `never`.

```
type A = {}


function test<T extends A, B extends Exclude<T, A>>(b: B) {

}

type Params = Parameters<typeof test>; // [b: never]
```

Comment: Not sure I get the 'extends All' part. How can I pass the following:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGBBATughgTwDwAMMAPjAIwkwBMAfDALwwDaBANGa1QLoDcAUKEiwARlnQoM2fGTqMmZXnwHhoMKCADCACwCmwANYooOAA46QceIiZgArgFthO9FwbV+SgJZwAFFB3QPqLorGqaugYAlJEwAN58MDCCqgBeOjpu6tp6+jAA9Hlh2QYoRKRUMAC0MJ4AdDq1ViAwAGQwAITBfAC+MDoANhAZ8YnJsGkZjFkRuQVFMygU1XUNMF3dQA)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const allFields = ['bar', 'zee'] as const;

function isUnsortableField<
    Prop extends PropertyKey,
    Unsortable extends Array<typeof allFields[number]> & Prop[],
    >(unsortable: [...Unsortable], field: any): field is Unsortable[number] {
    return unsortable.includes(field)
}

const unsortableOnes = ['bar'];

let field = 'baz'

if (isUnsortableField(['bar'], field)) {
    const x = field // "bar"
} else{
    const x = field // string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQMQJYFMEBMIwLwwDaA5AEZwBOxANDMQF7rrEC68uokUA3AFC8AzAK5hgUVOBioIAVUggKUOKQTo0mLAB5eMXTAAKFEAAcY6AB5R0YHAaPH0igJ4BpdE+o69ciAqUr0M0trWwBBCgo4J00oJwcQAXgkdWwIQjAhAFtSRxYAPhgAMjsTQhZPPRg8gAoRX0VlVQAuIgA6dp8-RvRymAEMbBa4MCcAShb+jSlcToaA9KycijYAby9dCnQoIQowGDqugNbUUQQhLHQIasnsUd4AX35OaH35OdUAeTBL-CIySlYfF4qlgNywv3+9GI-FQiWq0lm-lUKSw1RI5CovTBo1GMDWlWesHMvzBMAA9GSYAAiDFUh5mBAQdD4vSEmDEgikikwaAUE4AcwevCAA)

I have used `field: any` because of known [`Array.prototype.includes issue`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255)

AFAIK, there are several workarounds you can find in above issue, but all of them requires you to either redeclare built in type of ReadonlyArray or use type assertions. Hence, it is up to you to choose one.

Comment: I think with this I don't solve anything. I'm still stuck with `x = field // 'bar' | 'zee'.
I want to know that given:
- allFields: Array<'foo' | 'bar'>
- unsortable: Array<'foo'>

then x = field // 'bar'

Comment: @PaulFelice replace `unsortableOnes` with `["bar"]` and you will get `bar` as a field. If you want to use `Array<typeof allFields[number]>` type constraint you need to add it to function declaration instead of typing explicitly `unsortableOnes`

Comment: I replaced
`if (isUnsortableField(['bar'], field))`
with
`isUnsortableField(unsortableOnes, field)`
 
and getting `Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '("bar" | "zee")[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar" | "zee"'`

Comment: this is because `unsortableOnes` evaluated to string[]. You should make it either `as const` or use explicit `Array<typeof allFields[number]>`. Please keep in mind, if you use explicit type `Array<typeof allFields[number]>` for `unsortableOnes` , `field` variable will be the union of all elements in the `allFields`